# How can I modify my class to input stuff into my lists and find the mean of the class?

Tags: python, list, function, class

So I have created a class `Calculate` where I will define two functions `plus(self,x)` and `avg_over_totalnum(self)` that will modify a list `__init__(self, items)`.

`plus(self, x)` will add either x or the members of x to the list `self.items`.
Here x is one of the following: (1) a number, (2) a list, or (3) a tuple. If x is a number, it is added to the list directly. If x is a list or a tuple, its members are individually added to the list.

For instance if `self.items` == [5]

if `x == 45`, plus(self, x) will return `[5,45]`
if `x == [4,5]`, the output will be `[5,4,5]`

`avg_over_totalnum(self)` will compute and return the mean of the data maintained in the
collection

Here is my attempt at the code so far, which doesn't work at all...

```
class Calculate:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = list(items)
    def plus(self,x):
        if x in 123456789:
            return self.items + x
        else:
            return self.items.append(x)
    def avg_over_totalnum(self):
        return (sum(self.items))/(len(self.items))
```

What changes should I make in my code??

Comment: Consider the case where `self.items` is empty.  You will get a divide by zero error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `plus` method is a bit weird. It doesn't modify `self.items` in-place, so `self.items` don't get updated with `x`. Also, your if-statement is checking if `x` is in an integer, which doesn't make sense. Change `plus` with the function below:

```
def plus(self,x):
    if isinstance(x,(list,tuple)):
        self.items.extend(list(x))
    else:
        self.items.append(x)
    return self.items
```

Also to avoid ZeroDivisionError:

```
def avg_over_totalnum(self):
    return (sum(self.items))/(len(self.items)) if self.items else 0
```

Then it works fine.

```
c = Calculate([5])
print(c.plus(4))             # [5, 4]
print(c.plus([3,2]))         # [5, 4, 3, 2]
print(c.avg_over_totalnum()) # 3.5
```